How can i proceed further in this AI/ML project?
I have 10 datasets (.csv) each with 100,000 rows, with each row containing 5 inputs ( -4.0f to +4.0f) and a output column (0/1). I want to train a Neural Network using this and predict the test dataset that I was given (which has 100,000 rows too, but without output column filled).
I thought of creating a 5--(reLU)--> 32 --(reLU)--> 32 --(sigmoid) --> 1 Neural Network and train it with reward system like this [if (expec.op  ==0) reward=1- o/pfromNN; if (expec.op  ==1) reward= o/pfromNN].
How can I adjust weights of NN using this or How can I proceed further? I am a newbie to NN.
I thought of doing this like lunar lander module in gymnasium but since there are no states involved here I am confused

Your understanding is correct. You should follow these steps for setting up your neural network for binary classification:
Input Layer: 5 neurons (corresponding to your 5 inputs). First Hidden Layer: 32 neurons with ReLU activation. Second Hidden Layer: 32 neurons with ReLU activation. Output Layer: 1 neuron with Sigmoid activation (since this is a binary classification task).
The process of adjusting the weights of the neural network is generally handled through a method known as backpropagation, which is coupled with an optimization algorithm like Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD), Adam, or others.
Below is an example of how you can implement this using TensorFlow:
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# Define the model
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),                    
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')             
])


model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Assuming X_train and y_train are your data matrices
# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

